# How to install php5.5 on ubuntu 16.0.04

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, php-5.5

I am new to Ubuntu, using version 16.0.04. I am trying to install php5.5. after installation it show php5.6 when running the command php -v.

Help me to install php5.5 on Ubuntu 16.0.04

I want to run symfony framework, In PHP7.0 it get error.

Comment: instead if going back to php 5.5 just because you have an error, Why not solve the error. Just google.

Comment: So, you have PHP version 5.6, symfony has errors in PHP version 7 and therefore you want to install PHP 5.5. Sorry to say this but that makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your post is not clear.

Read From this post : 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/849808/installing-php5-5-on-ubuntu-16-with-apache2

The PHP 5.5 have been removed from ppa:ondrej/php, the lowest version is php5.6. Note that there are differences between php5.5 and php5.6, so you need to test your code. There is a major difference with object serialisation.